# solving T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n^3 + n*(log(n))^2

Tags: math, data-structures, runtime, recurrence

I am trying to solve a recurrence by using substitution method. The recurrence relation is:

```
T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n^3 + n*(log(n))^2
```

I tried to solve this also with master method.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs @ http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The last term is negligible compared to n^3.  Then use the Master's Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

First supstitution you can use is `n = 2^k`. Your recurrence becomes:

> T(2^k) = 4T(2^(k-1)) + 2^(3k) + 2^k * log(2^k)^2

or

> T(2^k) = 4T(2^(k-1)) + 2^(3k) + c * k^2 * 2^k

where `c = (log 2)^2`.

After another supstitution, `S(k) = T(2^k)` and dividing by `4^k` we get

> S(k) / 4^k = S(k-1) / 4^(k-1) + 2^k + c * k^2 / 2^k

Our final supstitution is `R(k) = S(k) / 4^k` and the new recurrence is

> R(k) = R(k-1) + 2^k + c * k^2 / 2^k

By telescoping (ie. summing these equations for k = 2, 3, ..., n) we get

> R(n) = R(1) + sum(2^k) + c * sum(k^2 / 2^k)

(where both sums go from k = 1 to k = n - 1).

Finally,

> R(n) = R(1) + 2^n - 1 + c * (6 - (n^2 + 2n + 3) / 2^(n-1)).

`T(2^k)` can easily be found from the last equation. For other values of `T(n)` (when n is not a power of 2), you don't have enough data without additional assumptions (continuity, for example).

Comment: +1. This doesn't telescope, but that's a minor quibble.

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of a time complexity, `T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n^3 + n*(log(n))^2` is the same as `T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n^3`.

Now using a [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), you have `a=4`, `b=2` and therefore `c = logb(a) = 2`. Because `n^c` grows slower than your `f(n) = n^3`, you fall into the third case and the time complexity is `O(n^3)`